# Split a list into multiple sublist based on element properties in Java

Tags: java, collections, apache-commons

Is there a way to split a list to multiple list?. Given list into two or more list based on a particular condition of it elements.

```
final List<AnswerRow> answerRows= getAnswerRows(.........);
final AnswerCollection answerCollections = new AnswerCollection();
answerCollections.addAll(answerRows);

The AnswerRow has properties like rowId, collectionId
```

based on collectionId i want to create one or more AnswerCollections

Comment: Yes there is. Did you doubt it is possible? What is you *specific* question about doing so?

Comment: based on list element properties can we splits into multiple list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want to group elements by `collectionId` you could try something like

```
List<AnswerCollection> collections = answerRows.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.collectionId))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> { AnswerCollection c = new AnswerCollection(); c.addAll(e.getValue()); return c; })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Above code will produce one `AnswerCollection` per `collectionId`.

---

With Java 6 and Apache Commons Collections, the following code produce the same results as the above code using Java 8 streams:

```
ListValuedMap<Long, AnswerRow> groups = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<Long, AnswerRow>();
for (AnswerRow row : answerRows)
    groups.put(row.collectionId, row);
List<AnswerCollection> collections = new ArrayList<AnswerCollection>(groups.size());
for (Long collectionId : groups.keySet()) {
    AnswerCollection c = new AnswerCollection();
    c.addAll(groups.get(collectionId));
    collections.add(c);
}
```

Comment: any way to do with Java 1.6?

Comment: @kapildas I extended my answer with code for Java 6 using Apache Commons Collections.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to split a list to multiple list?

Yes, You can do it like this:

```
answerRows.subList(startIndex, endIndex);
```

> Given list into two or more list based on a particular condition of it 
>   elements.

You'll have to calculate the `start` and `end` indices based on your specific condition and then you can mint the subList out of your ArrayList using the above function.

For Example, if you want to pass batches of 1000 `answerRows` to a specific function then you can do something like this:

```
int i = 0;
for(; i < max && i < answerRows.size(); i++) {
    if((i+1) % 1000 == 0) {
        /* Prepare SubList & Call Function */
        someFunction(answerRows.subList(i, i+1000));
    }
}
/* Final Iteration */
someFunction(answerRows.subList(i, answerRows.size() - 1));
```